# Spring on AppEngine: application slow startup and..... death?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

This thread seems dead, too: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/80d014fd5abd526f

Here's what happens:

- locally, by mvn gae:run, application works perfectly;
- I deploy the application to GAE;
- The first time I call the "/" url I wait a lot of time, but nothing strange: app is initializing, except it ends in a 500 error;
- I go ahead using my app.... all is right;
- I stop using app for 3 hours (e.g.);
- I return using it and.... it's dead! It takes again a lot of time to initialize! This is awful! 500 error again

Exception Stack Trace is:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (fc36c7e0f23da9e6) started at 2012/03/06 21:26:41.562 UTC and was still executing at 2012/03/06 21:27:42.117 UTC.
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Doesn't GAE java team solved this bug yet?

What can I do? I'd like to avoid setting a cron job for polling my url every 5 minutes :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the simple answer is to pay for the service and create a [resident instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131575/how-do-i-make-a-resident-instance-in-google-app-engine), then you won't be subject to the spin-up/tear-down which can be especially expensive with spring.

Another option is to trim your app so it doesn't take so long to start.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but during this "test" phase, I'm not going to pay anything. Thank you! :) For now, I created a cron job which keeps alive my app.... seems good too.

Comment: In some of google's docs I was reading yesterday (lost the link) they say they can recognize a cron job used to keep the app warm.  Not sure what they'll do about it, but just thought I'd bring it up.

Comment: well, playing Google's advocate, if the free tier is built around using spare cycles (spinning down an app when it's not in active use) then an app that stays artificially warm is basically stealing resources that could be used for other, legitimately active apps. If you only use your app every 3 hours, the resources could be allocated to other apps in the time between but because yours is resident due to artificial requests that resource sharing can't occur, meaning Google has to allocate more hardware to the free tier. At least... I imagine that's their view.

Answer (score 3):

let get something clear, warmup requests does not solve the DeadlineExceededException error.

The DeadlineExceededException you are seeing is due to startup taking longer than 60s.

warmup requests will NOT make the startup any quicker.

paid instances will NOT make the startup any quicker.

The startup cost is due mainly to classloading and resource loading on the classpath.
Anything that scans the classpath for classes/resources are slow to load.

to reduce the scan time depends on what frameworks your app is loading on startup. The usual suspects are Spring and JSF.

-lp

Comment: I agree that warmup requests will NOT make the startup any quicker. But from my experiments, jar scanning was only taking 3 seconds (on an F1), jar loading was actually about 7

Answer (score 2):

You can use [warmup requests](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Warmup_Requests) to bring your instance up to speed before a first user request is sent to it.

Note: this does not affect the delay time of first request when you have no instances running, it only helps when new instances (beyond existing ones) are spun up. However, it should help with the 500 error on the first request.